# How to react to messages sent by a webhook?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to add a reaction to a message sent by a webhook, but I don't know how to do it or how to get the ID of this message to be able to react to it. Here is my code:

```
const webhookClient = new Discord.WebhookClient(config.webhookID, config.webhookToken);

    message.delete();

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#00ffff')
        .setTitle(`Suggestion`)
        .setDescription(`${message.content}`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(`User ID: ${message.author.id}`);

    webhookMessage = webhookClient.send('', {
        username: message.author.username,
        avatarURL: message.author.avatarURL,
        embeds: [embed]
    });
    webhookMessage.react('').then(() => webhookMessage.react(''));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: It doesn't seem like `webhookMessage` is defined

Comment: @Syntle Yes, i get: `TypeError: webhookMessage.react is not a function` but I have no idea how to add reaction to this message or get its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be:

```js
webhookMessage = await webhookClient.send('',
{ username: message.author.username,
 avatarURL: message.author.avatarURL,
 embeds: [embed] }); 
await webhookMessage.react('');
await webhookMessage.react('');
```

Comment: I still get the same error. The code you suggest with me only changes that `await` is added. Or maybe there is a way to get the ID of the message sent by the webhook?

Comment: `webhookClient.send()` returns `Message` so I'm not sure as to why that isn't working for you, you should be able to get the message ID using `webhookMessage.id`

Comment: After all, it doesn't work for me. However, I found another way to respond to this message; I just fetched the last message from the channel and added a reaction to it. However, it is important to add a cooldown to the channel, because with a large amount of messages at once the bot incorrectly adds reactions.

Comment: Incorrectly adds reactions how? If by that you mean it's adding them in the wrong order then my current answer would fix that since it won't react with `` until it reacts with ``

Comment: No, it's adding `` to one message, `` to 2nd message, and for other it isn't adding any reactions. But if there will be 1 message for about 2 seconds, it's good.

Comment: I'm sure you can add some sort of delay between each webhook